# I want to be able to go through a list, and sort every letter in every word to least common to most common

Tags: python-3.x

**I am making a program that guesses your word, so it asks if a certain letter is in it, it would be most effective if I knew what letter was most common so the program can ask the least amount of questions.**

**for example:**

```
if my list is ["apple", "tree", "paper"]
```

**it must print out:**

```
["e", "p", "a", "r",...
```

(because p and a are most common they at the front of
 the list, and "t" would be at the back of the list because it only occurs once)

And if it would help; every word in the list has die same length.

Comment: How does `"apple"` have the same length as `"pear"`?!?

Comment: no, I just made some random words up, the very first question of my program would be, "how many characters does the word have you are thinking of? ". So all the words in the list would be the same length, I just mentioned the fact incase it would help. Thanks for taking the time to read it!

Answer (score 0):

Use `Counter` for counting.

```
from collections import Counter

l = ["apple", "tree", "paper"]
[element for element, frequency in Counter(''.join(l)).most_common()]
# => ['p', 'e', 'a', 'r', 'l', 't']
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
import collections
...
lst = ["apple", "tree", "paper"]
counter = collections.Counter(''.join(lst))

print(counter.most_common())
# [('p', 4), ('e', 4), ('a', 2), ('r', 2), ('l', 1), ('t', 1)]

print([t[0] for t in counter.most_common()])
# ['p', 'e', 'a', 'r', 'l', 't']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to be case insensitive convert the strong to lower case and use.

for your purpose, you can use the counter in python collections which will be effective. below is the code sample.

```
from collections import Counter
words = ["apple", "tree", "paper"]
cnt = Counter()
for word in words:
  word = word.lower() #incase u want it case insensitive
  for letter in word:
    cnt[letter]+=1

print(cnt)
```

finally convert the counter to dictionary if needed

```
count_dict = dict(cnt)
```